# Disable horizontal scrolling in scrollview (xcode 6)

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, xcode6

I'm trying to disable the horizontal scrolling from my scrollview but I don't know how to do it. I tried to follow some tutorials and other answers from stackoverflow but it's my first time using scrollview and I'm a little bit lost.

At the moment the scrolling is vertical, which is fine, but I would like to lock the horizontal scroll.

I'm using storyboard in xcode 6.

I tried again with:

```
CGSize size = CGSizeMake (self.view.frame.size.width, 800.0);
[UIScrollView setContentSize:size]; - ERROR
```

Error: **'No known class method for selector setContentSize'**

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the content size to the width of the screen or less in order to stop horizontal scrolling using:

```
CGSize contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.view.frame.size.width, scrollableHeight);
[myScrollView setContentSize:contentSize];
```

Write this in the viewDidLoad method in the corresponding file.

[Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/Library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIScrollView_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIScrollView/contentSize)

Comment: Hello,
When I put that code I have an error in the "scrollableHeight"...! Any help, please?
Thanks for your answer.

Comment: You should be passing a CGFloat into the scrollableHeight parameter

Comment: When I write 800 as scrollableHeight it displays an another error: 'Initializing CGSize with an expression of incompatible type CGSize'. (first line). What can I do? Thanks again Ignacy.

Comment: Updated the first message.

Comment: `CGSize` should not be a pointer, so remove the asterisk (`*`). The declaration should be `CGSize contentSize = ...`

Comment: Thanks evolution, now I have another error in the second line. I have updated again the first message with the info. Much appreciated.

Comment: @JulienKP You're calling `setContentMode:` on the `UIScrollView` class - that's not right. You need to be using the actual name of your UIScrollView variable. In Ignacy's example, it's `myScrollView`. Replace this with whatever your variable is called (probably linked to in your storyboard or XIB file)

Comment: Hi again guys,
Where can I set the name of my UIViewScroll? I tried to go to my Storyboard file and set the Restoration ID as myScrollView but it's still not working...!

Comment: When you create an outlet, you set it a name e.g. 'myScrollView'.  You can then access it in the .m file using 'self.myScrollView' or just 'myScrollView' if you have synthesised it